# diff -y usage of |'s vs. >'s and <'s in the output

Tags: diff

I have two files:

```
cat test1
1
3
5
11
13
17
19
21
22
23
29
30
32
33
34
39
```

and

```
cat test2
2
4
6
10
12
20
21
22
23
24
29
30
31
32
34
49
```

When I diff them, I get:

```
diff -y test1 test2
1                                                             | 2
3                                                             | 4
5                                                             | 6
11                                                            | 10
13                                                            | 12
17                                                            | 20
19                                                            <
21                                                              21
22                                                              22
23                                                              23
                                                              > 24
29                                                              29
30                                                              30
                                                              > 31
32                                                              32
33                                                            <
34                                                              34
39                                                            | 49
```

The meaning and behavior of when diff -y produces "|" instead of "<" or ">" has proven very difficult to dig up in spite of googling. I understand what it means, I think (i.e. "19 <" instead of "19 | 21" b/c 21 is present later in file1 to match up with the aforementioned 21 in file2) but it strikes me as obtuse b/c the output of a given line is being influenced by subsequent ones, and depending on output formatting there is nothing indicating that the command is doing this or why.

Is there a way to suppress this behavior or make it more transparent?

I want to suppress common lines in my output, and the problem is without the common lines, this next output is very confusing (for reasons I outlined above - the common lines give context as to "why are some of these |'s and the others are >'s or <'s?", so looking at the below output there's seemingly no answer to that question):

```
diff -y --suppress-common-lines test1 test2
1                                                             | 2
3                                                             | 4
5                                                             | 6
11                                                            | 10
13                                                            | 12
17                                                            | 20
19                                                            <
                                                              > 24
                                                              > 31
33                                                            <
39                                                            | 49
```

I'd basically like it to be either |'s -OR- all <'s and >'s

Comment: `diff` is not part of bash. Tag diffutils, not bash.

Comment: Also, I'm very skeptical that you _should_ be using diff at all; it's utter overkill if, f/e, all you care about is which numbers are added vs removed

Comment: ...that said, if you read `diff`'s documentation, as with `man diff`, you'll see that which of several available formats is actually used. Not all those formats involve `<`s or `|`s or `>`s at all in the first place.

Comment: ...a bit of important background: `diff` exists not to compare two files but to _calculate an optimal transform between_ two files. Building a patch to transform one thing into the other means involving a bunch of information (like ordering) that wouldn't be needed just to answer the question "which lines were removed from file a when compared to file b?" or similar.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the only diffutils tag that was available was android-diffutils. I removed the bash tag. RE: your other concerns, I've tried `comm` as well, however its formatting or lack thereof requires invoking a bunch of other commands like `paste` and `column`, or `awk`,  which also seemed like overkill. I'm trying to get this in a table-like output, hence the use of "-y", sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Let's back up. What are you actually trying to accomplish? (You shouldn't need to postprocess output from `comm` at all if you tell it to directly return the results you want).